# Collecting results into a map from a yaml file with yq, values are unexpectedly null

Tags: bash, yq

I am trying to get the results of the following structure from a yaml file

```
applications:
  a:
    enabled: true
    persistence: true
  b:
    enabled: true
    persistence: true
  c:
    enabled: true
    persistence: false
```

Using yq by [mikefarah](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) v4.30.4:

```
yq '.applications | to_entries | .[] |select(.value.enabled == true) | .key: .value.persistence' manifest.yml
```

But I get this output:

```
[{a: null}, {b: null}, {c: null}]
```

Trying other examples I get the following result

```
yq '.applications | to_entries | .[] |select(.value.enabled == true) | {.key: {.persistence: .value.persistence}}' manifest.yml
a:
  null: true
b:
  null: true
c:
  null: false
```

The result should be

```
a: true, b: true, c: false
```

Comment: Thank you for specifying which yq implementation you were asking about; that always makes answering easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *most immediate* problem could be solved by more parens (`(.key: .value.persistence)` instead of `.key: .value.persistence`), but to get a single map as output, you should use a reducer:

```
yq '
(.applications
| to_entries
| .[]
| select(.value.enabled == true)
) as $i ireduce({}; .[$i.key] = $i.value.persistence)
' manifest.yml
```

...yields as output:

```yaml
a: true
b: true
c: false
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I completed the command with the following to fulfill a request we have to implement : `yq '(.applications | to_entries | .[] | select(.value.enabled == true)) as $i ireduce({}; .[$i.key] = $i.value.persistence)' manifest.yml | awk '{print "\"" $0 "\""}' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' | sed  's/^/[/' | sed s/$/]/` and get this output `["purchase: true","address: true","payment: false"]`

Comment: That's a ... very unfortunate request. You don't need sed to fulfill it, though, as long as your requirements are concerned only with semantics and not with syntax. (Even if they _are_ concerned with syntax, tell yq to emit JSON and you can get that output from it).

Comment: I try this `yq -o=json -I=0 '(.applications | to_entries | .[] | select(.value.enabled == true)) as $i ireduce({}; .[$i.key] = $i.value.persistence)'` manifest.yml` and get this output `{"purchase":true,"address":true,"payment":false}` but we need this `["purchase:true","address:true","payment:false"]`

Comment: Right, `ireduce` was correct when you wanted a map as output, but when you want an array it's simpler. `yq -o=json -I=0 '[(.applications | to_entries | .[] | select(.value.enabled == true)) | (.key + ": " + .value.persistence)]' manifest.yml`